Laravel reverb Websocket does not connect correctly in cpanel host with SSL
Websocket doesn't connect in frontend when application is on cpanel host and the stranger thing is if we open reverb port in other browser tab and take 'not found' as response, It will start to connect in another tabs frontend!
And if you close and reopen browser, The same thing will happen again!
My reverb config:
        'reverb' => [
            'host' => env('REVERB_SERVER_HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
            'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 8080),
            'hostname' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
            'options' => [
                'tls' => [
                    'local_cert' =>  '/path/to/certificate.pem',
                    'local_pk' => '/path/to/private_key.pem',
                    'cafile' => '/path/to/cabundle.pem',
                ],
            ],
            'max_request_size' => env('REVERB_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE', 10_000),
            'scaling' => [
                'enabled' => env('REVERB_SCALING_ENABLED', false),
                'channel' => env('REVERB_SCALING_CHANNEL', 'reverb'),
                'server' => [
                    'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
                    'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
                ],
            ],
            'pulse_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_PULSE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
            'telescope_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_TELESCOPE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
        ],

Laravel echo:

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'reverb',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT,
    forceTLS: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

If SSL without CA bundle has been installed in cpanel host and in reverb config set 'verify_peer' parameter to false, it will work without any problem but our new SSL installed in cpanel has CA bundle so we cannot set 'verify_peer' to false.
